# for loop ignores condition

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to write a function to convert hex number into decimal,but I'm having issues with what I assume is error in for loop of my first function.I am unable to catch whatever character is on the end of my array and it loops one additional time.I've removed extra code and left only relevant parts.I assume this could be fixed by using get/putchar but I really wanna know what's causing it. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int check;

    char num_input[20];

    scanf("%s",num_input);

    int hex_check(char *hex_input){
        int i;
        int n;
        for(i=0;hex_input[i]!='\n' || hex_input[i]!=EOF;i++){
            if(isxdigit(hex_input[i])!=0){
                n++;
                printf("\nTRUE");
            }
            else{
                n=0;
                printf("\nFALSE");
                return n;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
    check=hex_check(num_input);
    printf("\n%d",check);

    return 0;
}
```

Output when inputting 123(I was using n to pass number of digits to other part of the function,0 if number is not hex):

```
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the condition

```
hex_input[i]!='\n' || hex_input[i]!=EOF
```

is always true: the input cannot be a `'\n'` and an `EOF` together at the same time.

The other issue is that you will never see an `EOF` in your string; however, you will see a null terminator, i.e. `'\0'`

Change to

```
hex_input[i]!='\n' && hex_input[i]!='\0'
```

to fix the problem.

Another thing that you are missing is the initialization of `n`: you should set it to zero before your loop starts incrementing it.

Finally, nested functions are not allowed by the ANSI standard, making your code non-portable. Consider moving the code of `hex_check` to the outer level, and declare it `static` to ensure that it is not visible from other modules.

Comment: Doesn't work, i tried it that way and with both individually.If i add 2nd if condition that's only true if char is equal to '\n' or EOF,that condition wont trigger though.

Comment: @user3533671 Take a look at the edit. [Here is a running demo](http://ideone.com/1lbWc8).

Comment: That fixed it, I tried using '\0' but it failed because n wasn't initialized, though I didn't notice it earlier...

Comment: One more question, shouldn't it be irrelevant if I use && or || in this case since loop should stop on either of those conditions?

Comment: @user3533671 You need an `&&`, because `||` will not stop the loop when it sees `'\0'` and cause it to return zero (incorrectly).